# OkHttp3 not working with Kotlin (Android), gives a fatal error

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I am facing quite a bit of difficulty using OkHttp3 with Kotlin on Android Studio development, as it keeps telling me I have a "fatal error" even though I followed the steps for using OkHttp3. I have added the internet permission in my manifest file as well. Below is my code for my title fragment:

```
package com.example.materialdesigntest

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import okhttp3.*
import java.io.IOException

class TitleFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_title, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val signInButton: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.signInButton)
        val createAccountButton: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.createAccountButton)
        val internetButton: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.internetButton)
        val endText: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.internetResponse)

        var client1 = OkHttpClient()
        var request1 = Request.Builder()
            .url("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
            .build()

        client1.newCall(request1).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
                endText.text = response.body.toString()
            }
        })

        Log.i("TitleFragment", "request Complete.")

        createAccountButton.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_titleFragment_to_createAccountFragment)
        }
    }


}
```

I am also attaching my error logs from Logcat as well:

```
2020-05-20 10:18:32.821 31008-31008/com.example.materialdesigntest D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2020-05-20 10:18:32.979 31008-31162/com.example.materialdesigntest W/erialdesigntes: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
2020-05-20 10:18:33.103 31008-31162/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: com.example.materialdesigntest, PID: 31008
    kotlin.NotImplementedError: An operation is not implemented: Not yet implemented
        at com.example.materialdesigntest.TitleFragment$onViewCreated$1.onResponse(TitleFragment.kt:50)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:206)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2020-05-20 10:18:33.182 31008-31008/? D/ViewRootImpl@7fbfe7a[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
2020-05-20 10:18:33.182 31008-31008/? D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@76366da[MainActivity]
2020-05-20 10:18:33.182 31008-31008/? D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2020-05-20 10:18:33.197 31008-31162/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 31008 SIG: 9
```

Thanks!

UPDATE: I removed the TODO comments but still giving me this error log:

```
2020-05-20 10:34:47.165 6428-6515/com.example.materialdesigntest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: com.example.materialdesigntest, PID: 6428
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:9812)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1841)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:26338)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:26338)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:26338)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:26338)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:26338)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:26338)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.requestLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:3172)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:26338)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.requestLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:3172)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:26338)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:26338)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.requestLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:3172)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:26338)
        at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:10760)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6830)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6630)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6582)
        at com.example.materialdesigntest.TitleFragment$onViewCreated$1.onResponse(TitleFragment.kt:48)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:206)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

UPDATE 2 - Got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `TODO()` throws an exception so just try to remove these lines: `TODO("Not yet implemented")`

Next error: you can change views only from the main thread. So instead of:

```kotlin
override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
    endText.text = response.body.toString()
}
```

you have to post job to the main thread like this:

```kotlin
override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
    requireActivity().runOnUiThread { 
        endText.text = response.body.toString()
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not changing much, and my app still crashes.

Comment: It works now, but my result is: okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@62c589a. How can I change that to the actual data from the site?

Comment: @RohitKarthik you have to parse the response for example with Gson to access the data you need